# Data types appropriate for Keras .flow_from_directory?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I was hoping to find a list of "data types" (not sure of appropriate wording but example .jpg, .tif, etc) that can be fed into the .flow_from_directory in keras. Right now I am at work and cant test this but my "images" are saved as tensors size (#, width, length, height, other(pet or ct w/ contrast)) in ".mat" file. . pet =  , ct w/ contrast = 0

example(1, 48, 48, 32, 1) which is a volume from a PET scan.

As an aside to further complicate the matter to load the data manually I have to do something like below to get the array so that might also complicate the matter later if ".mat" files are compatible with .flow_from_directory.

```
test = scipy.io.loadmat(directory)['1.mat']
```

Comment: Only `png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, ppm, tif, tiff` are [supported](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/362fe9f8daf556151328eb5d02bd5ae638c653b8/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1868). If you have enough memory, you can load all the data and the use them, otherwise you can write a custom generator that load images. I don't see what the complexity of loading them manually might be.

Comment: dang I didnt think about looking at the code...Thank you!!